# Question about dual booting

Tags: boot, 14.04, dual-boot

I'm very new to Ubuntu(and any non-windows OS in general) and I'm currently running windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual-booted. I'm not the only person to use this computer, so I was wondering if it was possible to have it boot into windows 8.1 unless I tell it to boot into Ubuntu. It currently starts at a purple screen and allows me to choose windows or Ubuntu or a couple other options, which is "annoying" to the other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by modifying your grub file.  I use Grub Customizer for this purpose:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After installation, start the program by opening the dash, and entering 'grub'.  On the tab marked 'General Settings' you can set the default OS to start, and the timeout before it automatically starts that OS

Answer (score 0):

try using easy bcd to dual boot
http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

find the instructions on this page
https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/